# Particles around a sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

I'm new to the CoCos2D development. I have checked out some tutorials and went on trying to develop a little idea. 
I have checked some partical tutorials and it all looks nice but I still have some questions about it. I have seen how to call a particle and let it follow wherever you click on the layer and so on but I need something more.

Let's say I have several circle shaped sprites on my Layer. Is it possible to do the following: click on a sprite and then a partical trail should go around the sprite so you as a player can see it is selected. The particale should keep circling around the sprite until I select another circle shaped sprite which result in dissappearing of the previous particle trail and appearing onto the new selected sprite.

Is this possible with the particle system or should I look for another way of doing this ? Any type of help is appreciated.

kind regards

Comment: yes that's possible, you just need to create a particle "ring" effect using a particle editor preferably

Comment: Ok thanks. I have found the software Particle Designer for this.
However..how does the particle now the size of the sprite itself? Some circles are bigger then others so I probably would have to get the sizes of the sprite and pass them through while adding the particle ? Is this the correct way of thinking or am I missing something? :)
PS: I will definitely check out your site !

Comment: you can design one particle for a specific size, or tweak the particle in code based on the sprite size if you have many different sized sprites

Comment: K thanks ! I think I know what to do now.